# Why are my events not showing up in the Firebase Analytics console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

When my apps starts, asks a question to the user. I save the event like this:

```
Bundle bundle0 = new Bundle();
bundle0.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, "usertype1");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("my_user_type", bundle0);
```

This value can be **usertype1** or **usertype2**

When im in the Firebase Dashboard i cant find the anwsers anywhere, in fact, the event tab shows this:

[image]

tipo_usuario == my_user_type
Valor = value

As u can see, it shows "value 0"

But, when im using the **DebugView**, i can see the usertype1 or 2 reaching firebase.

What im missing?

Comment: How much time did u wait? Firebase took 24+Hours to update the dashboard, that's why DebugView is used for fast tests and debug.

Comment: 48+ Hours and still nothing.

Comment: Did you guys find anything??

Answer (score 0):

Value displays the accumulated value of all "tipo_usario" events but in order for the value to accumulate you cannot use putString(), instead use putLong() or putDouble(). https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param#VALUE

From what I gather you are looking to differentiate between two different types of users, so you should probably look into user properties instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/properties